# @username not working for someone

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just had a conversation with someone at this question that I posted: [how-to-allow-jquery-to-consume-service-cross-domain-in-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246846/how-to-allow-jquery-to-consume-service-cross-domain-in-express)

He was a tiny bit belligerent but he knew what he was talking about and .. right when he had convinced me, he deleted his answer entirely. Actually it was shortly after I invited him to rephrase his answer to include points in the comments we had discussed, and receive credit for the answer.

During that conversation something I noticed is that he could use `@robertotomas` in his responses, but when I used `@Quentin` it simply disappeared. I could not add his username paired with the at-sign at all. I want to invite his return to provide the answer, but there is no private message system here — and that's something I agree with. :)

But if I could at least use `@Quentin` in  comment on my own question, I imagine there are searches he could do that would include the question in the results that way.

Why did `@Quentin` not work? Will it work in comments on my own question?

Comment: Pings at the original poster (Quentin in that case), will be removed automatically from the comments.

Comment: ... as they always get notified anyway.